# material-ui cannot build class name jss-* when first render on next.js

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I have a problem with material-ui on nextjs.
When the page first renders class name look like `makeStyles-container-36` and the page looks like load CSS failed, but I click a link to other pages the class name would be `jss43` and CSS look like successful.